# Is there a way to stop macro modifications from undoing when Updating Word Liked Tables?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I have written a macro to optimize the routine modifications (changing font, row height, size, etc.) I always make for the tables linked from Excel to Word. Now the problem is that when I update the tables (via right click/update Link), all the macro modifications are undone. Is there a remedy for this problem? (Note: the same doesn’t happen if the modifications are made manually (without macro). I use Word 2016.  I have found this problem is not specific to my macro and is the case for every macro running on linked Word tables. See the following simple example which just autofit a table and determine its height).
I have also posted this question on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-I-stop-macro-formatting-done-on-a-linked-Word-table-from-undoing-when-updating-it-via-right-click-update-link)

```
Sub autofit()

' autofit Macro
    
    Selection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Height = CentimetersToPoints(0.01)
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your macro in your question? Which version of Word? https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask  -- have you considered using instead Quick Tables or Table Styles for your formatting?

Comment: (1) I encourage you to indent your code properly. (2) Try to produce a ***minimal*** example — the shortest possible macro that demonstrates the problem. I see that you have eight ```Selection.Borders(…).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone``` statements; I suspect you would have the same problem if you deleted seven of them — or even all eight. (3) What do you mean by “when I update the tables”?

Comment: I have edited my question to address your comments.